# Filter is not refreshing propely

Tags: java, filter

My listview has a filter which works half of the way that I want.

For example, my database is:
Good morning, Good night 

If I type Good, shows--->  Good morning; Good night

If I type, Good m, shows---> Good morning

If I delete the "m", Good , shows ---> Good morning

If I add the "n" Good n ----> It is blank

So I want that refresh the listview for each letter. I'm not quite sure if the problem is on the perform filtering or publish results or on TextChangedListener.I have googled it and found some examples, but they didn't work. Thanks in advance.

I almost solved it when on the perform filtering was like this :

```
 protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
 FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
         //  implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() != 0 && constraint.length()*vocabLista.size() != 0)
            // constraint.length()*vocabLista.size() != 0 for every time that haven't showed results
            {
                // perform filtering operation
```

Here is my code:

**TextChangedListener:**

```
      @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Text [" + s + "]");
            j_adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            j_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

**Filter:**

```
 @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                        // We implement here the filter logic
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() != 0)
            // && constraint.length()*vocabLista.size() != 0

            {
                // perform filtering operation
                List<Vocabulario> nVocabLista = new ArrayList<Vocabulario>();

                for (Vocabulario p : vocabLista) {

                    if (p.getEnglish().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) | p.getPortugues().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) | p.getPortugues().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) | p.getEnglish().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))

                    {
                        nVocabLista.add(p);
                    }

                }

                results.values = nVocabLista;
                results.count = nVocabLista.size();

            } else

            {

                {
                    // No filter implemented return all the list
                    results.values = origVocabLista;
                    results.count = origVocabLista.size();

                }
            }

        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results)
    {

        // inform the adapter about the new list filtered
        vocabLista = (List<Vocabulario>) results.values;

        if (results.count != 0)

        {

            results.values = vocabLista;
            results.count = vocabLista.size();

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        else

        {

            notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    }
}
```